# Failed to lookup view Node JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, ejs

When I am trying to render the URL to display *index.js* in the browser, the following error occurs:

```
**Error:** Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "D:\NodeJs\Example\5expressnodjsexmp\views"
```

Here is my application code given below

```
//Headers
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path    = require('path');
var app = express();

//body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
// set static path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

// EJS View engine
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));

app.get('/',function(req,res){

   res.render('index');

});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server Started at 3000.....');
});
```

**Error Thrown:**

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "D:\NodeJs\Example\5expressnodjsexmp\views"
    at EventEmitter.render (D:\NodeJs\Example\5expressnodjsexmp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\NodeJs\Example\5expressnodjsexmp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at D:\NodeJs\Example\5expressnodjsexmp\app.js:31:6
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\NodeJs\Example\5expressnodjsexmp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\NodeJs\Example\5expressnodjsexmp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\NodeJs\Example\5expressnodjsexmp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\NodeJs\Example\5expressnodjsexmp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\NodeJs\Example\5expressnodjsexmp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\NodeJs\Example\5expressnodjsexmp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\NodeJs\Example\5expressnodjsexmp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

**Project Structure**
The above code Project structure image :
[image: The above code Project structure image]

Comment: Just rename the file name to index.js to index.ejs

Answer (score 2):

Rename the view file `index.js` to `index.ejs`

Comment: also if I remember correctly, there is no need for this line - `app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));` if you're using `views` directory.